# Setting a simple retry function in python while parsing html

Tags: python, html, loops, parsing

I am trying to make this function run itself again if it doesnt find the information on the page.

I thought this would be a solution, but it doesnt work. I am unsure how to make the loop of the scrape happen, with simple functionality. I tried using the retrying module, but it has issues installing, so a hard code solution would be ideal.

My code is below

```
import time, requests, webbrowser, sys, os, re, json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style, init
import subprocess as s

url = "http://notimportant.com"

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

def getIds():
    global product_id
    for script in scripts:
        if 'spConfig =' in script.getText():
            #idlive = True
            regex = re.compile(r'var spConfig = new Product.Config\((.*?)\);')
            match = regex.search(script.getText())
            spConfig = json.loads(match.groups()[0])
            for key, attribute in spConfig['attributes'].iteritems():
                for option in attribute['options']:
                    if option['label_uk'] == size:
                        label = option['label_uk'].strip()
                        for product_id in option['products']:
                            print(Fore.CYAN + "Size Found!")
                            print product_id, "-", label
                            #str = product_id
                            #productsizeid = str
        else:
            print(Fore.RED + "Sizes not live yet")
            print("Retrying in 10 seconds . . .")
            time.sleep(10)
            print("Trying again. . .")
            getIds()
```

Comment: are you by any chance missing the brakcets after calling getIds?

Comment: thats just a typo on my copy and paste, with the brackets, it will print the ids found and also the else message, so it is still incorrect

Comment: Have you tried iteratively and not recursively ? The problem I see here is if the script doesn't have 'spConfig =' in it, it will loop indefinitely. Maybe it is what you want but the call stack will be overloaded if it is recursive.

Comment: In addition, can you precise what it's not working ? No error message ? No print ? No loop ?

Answer (score 0):

iteration will be the preferred method 
something like:

```
url = "http://notimportant.com"
size_alive  = false
while not size_alive:
           do_the_scraping_function(#the function should set size_alive=true when it finds spConfig =' in script.getText())
           print("retrying in 10 seconds")
           time.sleep(10)
```